# including activity on popup window

Tags: android

I am trying to create a popup window. I am including activity on the popup. The activity has the tabhost on it. when i run the activity without popup separately , the tabs are visible. but when i add the same on the popup, the tabs are invisible. I can only see the content inside the tabs.

Here is my code for calling popup-

```
public void createVideoEvent(View arg0) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater
            = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_event_create, null);
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
            popupView,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    View new_event_button = (View) findViewById(R.id.button);
    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(new_event_button);

}
```